# How to filter data from multiple documents by date Firestore, Android,Java

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

Could someone help me with a query I'm trying? I have put some test data to Firestore to test my app. I want to query the data of the current users signed in and then get only the data that was saved to the database today. I want to get the highest and lowest temperature of the current day and also the same for a pulse. At the moment my code gets all of those, but when I try to compare the current date to the one in the database, so I can retrieve only the data from today, I only get the newest one. So example if I have to documents from to day, I only get the latest one. 
My code looks like this at the moment:

```
package com.example.wht;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.wht.model.WhtItem;
import com.example.wht.ui.WhtRecyclerAdapter;
import com.example.wht.util.WhtApi;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


public class MainPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView highestPulse, lowestPulse;
    private TextView highestTemp, lowestTemp;
    private TextView time;
    private ImageButton tempButton;
    private CardView pulseCardView, tempCardView;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private List<Integer> tempItemList;
    private List<Integer> pulseItemList;
    private List<WhtItem> itemList;
    private String htemp;
    private int minTemp ;
    private String ltemp;
    private int maxPulse;
    private String hpulse;
    private int minPulse;
    private String lpulse;
    private int maxTemp;
    private String dateAdded;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    //Firestore conneection
    private CollectionReference collectionReference = db.collection("whtitem");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        highestPulse = findViewById(R.id.highest_pulse_mainpage);
        lowestPulse = findViewById(R.id.lowest_pulse_mainpage);
        highestTemp = findViewById(R.id.highest_temperature_text);
        lowestTemp = findViewById(R.id.lowest_temp_text);
        time = findViewById(R.id.time_mainpage); //TARKISTA
        tempButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        pulseCardView = findViewById(R.id.pulse_cardView);
        tempCardView = findViewById(R.id.body_heat_cardview);
        tempItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        pulseItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        itemList = new ArrayList<>();

        tempButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        pulseCardView.setOnClickListener(this);
        tempCardView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.imageButton:
                //TODO go to temp_history_activity
                break;
            case R.id.pulse_cardView:
                //TODO go to pulse_history_activity
                break;
            case R.id.body_heat_cardview:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainPageActivity.this, TimeTempActivity.class));
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.profile:
                //add take users to add journal
                if (user != null && firebaseAuth!=null){
                  startActivity(new Intent(MainPageActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
                    //finish();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.temp_history:
               /*if (user != null && firebaseAuth!=null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainPageActivity.this, TempHistoryActivity.class));
                    //finish();
                }
                break;*/
            case R.id.pulse_history:
               /*if (user != null && firebaseAuth!=null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainPageActivity.this, PulseHistoryActivity.class));
                    //finish();
                }
                break;*/
            case R.id.time_in_temp_history:
               if (user != null && firebaseAuth!=null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainPageActivity.this, TimeTempActivity.class));
                    //finish();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_signout:
                //signout
                if (user != null && firebaseAuth!=null){
                    firebaseAuth.signOut();
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainPageActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    //finish();
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        final Date cDate = new Date(ts.getTime());
        final String currentDate =  DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy", cDate).toString();

        collectionReference.whereEqualTo("userId", WhtApi.getInstance()
                .getUserId())
                .whereEqualTo("date", cDate)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){

                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot whtitems : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                WhtItem whtItem = whtitems.toObject(WhtItem.class);
                                itemList.add(whtItem);

                                Date dAdded = whtItem.getDate();
                                dateAdded = DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy", dAdded).toString();

                                tempItemList.add(whtItem.getTemperature());
                                pulseItemList.add(whtItem.getPulse());

                                maxTemp = Collections.max(tempItemList);
                                htemp = "Korkein: " + maxTemp + " astetta";
                                minTemp = Collections.min(tempItemList);
                                ltemp = "Matalin: " + minTemp + " astetta";
                                maxPulse = Collections.max(pulseItemList);
                                hpulse = "Korkein: " + maxPulse + " bpm";
                                minPulse = Collections.min(pulseItemList);
                                lpulse = "Matalin: " + minPulse + " bpm";
                            }
                            if (currentDate.equals(dateAdded)) {
                                highestTemp.setText(htemp);
                                lowestTemp.setText(ltemp);
                                highestPulse.setText(hpulse);
                                lowestPulse.setText(lpulse);
                            }else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainPageActivity.this, "Ei dataa tältä päivältä", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainPageActivity.this, "Virhe dataa haettaessa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainPageActivity.this, "Ei dataa näytettäväksi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

    }
}
```

And here is my POJO:

```
package com.example.wht.model;


import com.google.firebase.firestore.ServerTimestamp;

import java.util.Date;


public class WhtItem {
    private String nameUser, userId;
    private String password;
    private int temperature, pulse;
    private @ServerTimestamp java.util.Date date;
    private int duration;

    public WhtItem() {
    }

    public WhtItem(String nameUser, String userId, String password, int temperature, int pulse, java.util.Date date, int duration) {
        this.nameUser = nameUser;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.password = password;
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.pulse = pulse;
        this.date = date;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getNameUser() {
        return nameUser;
    }

    public void setNameUser(String nameUser) {
        this.nameUser = nameUser;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemperature(int temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public int getPulse() {
        return pulse;
    }

    public void setPulse(int pulse) {
        this.pulse = pulse;
    }

    public java.util.Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date dateAdded) {
        this.date = dateAdded;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}
```

My Firestore documents are in the following form:
[Firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Stno.png)

Can someone tell where am I going wrong with this? I tried to google and search but no luck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the actual code in your question not pictures. Some pictures may not be readable, and anyone wanting to help you can't copy the code from a picture into their own Deve environment.

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a screenshot of it. Beside that, please also add what Dragonthoughts asked for.

Comment: Thank for your comments! I have edited my question to include the complete code as code and a picture of the database.

Answer (score 1):

the query for filter document data of **FirebaseStore** :

```
 Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(TABLE_KEY_COMMENT)
                .whereEqualTo("disucssionId",discussionID)
                .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
```

try to use like this query and pass correct param